# cmake constantly ignoring GIT_TAG when building external project

Tags: git, opencv, cmake

One of dependencies in my project is OpenCV, which is compiled from source. After it's downloaded, cmake always trying to checkout compile latest master commit, and I need tag 3.4.2. cmake is of version 3.1.3. This is related part of the cmake script:

```cmake
include(ExternalProject)
set(OCV_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=. -DCMAKE_SOURCE_DIR=${SOURCE_DIR}
        -DCMAKE_BINARY_DIR=${BINARY_DIR} -DENABLE_FAST_MATH=ON -DWITH_EIGEN=1
        -DWITH_TBB=ON -DENABLE_BUILD_HARDENING=ON
        -DWITH_MATLAB=ON -DWITH_GTK=ON -DWITH_GTK_2_X=ON
        -DBUILD_LIST=core,features2d,highgui,improc,calib3d,imgcodecs,videoio,video)

if( NOT OCV_TAG )
  set(OCV_TAG 3.4.2)
endif()

ExternalProject_Add(opencv
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git opencv
    DOWNLOAD_DIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/lib/
    GIT_TAG     "${OCV_TAG}"
    SOURCE_DIR   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/src/lib/opencv
    BINARY_DIR   ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/lib/opencv
    INSTALL_DIR  ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin/lib/opencv
    TMP_DIR      ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp
    CMAKE_ARGS   ${OCV_CMAKE_ARGS}
    BUILD_COMMAND make -j ${N}
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
    UPDATE_COMMAND
    TEST_COMMAND make -j ${N} # make in the end because of some bug (?) that breaks links for libraries
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 0
    BUILD_ALWAYS 0
    DOWNLOAD_NO_PROGRESS 0
    UPDATE_DISCONNECTED 1
    LOG_DOWNLOAD 0
    LOG_CONFIGURE 0
    LOG_INSTALL 0
    LOG_BUILD 0
    LOG_UPDATE 0
    LOG_TEST 0
    GIT_PROGRESS 1
)
```

I tried these variations of related GIT_TAG string:

```cmake
if( NOT OCV_TAG )
  set(OCV_TAG "3.4.2")
endif()
...
GIT_TAG     "${OCV_TAG}"
```

```cmake
GIT_TAG     "3.4.2"
```

```cmake
GIT_TAG     3.4.2
```

```cmake
GIT_TAG     origin/master/3.4.2
```

```cmake
GIT_TAG     master/3.4.2
```

And nothing of that worked, even though according to documentation it must work.. Someone got this issue/or have actually working example with cmake 3.1.3?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option `GIT_TAG` works only in conjunction with `GIT_REPOSITORY` one, when CMake performs a project's downloading by itself.

If you perform downloading manually (via `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`), then you should perform adjusting the branch manually too.

Comment: can you please explain "CMake performs a project's downloading by itself" statement? (because downloading made by CMake automatically, I don't do any manual interaction in build process)

Comment: By "automatically" I meant CMake chooses appropriate command for download the project. This is opposite to setting `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND`, where you explicitely said what to do on download step. Probably, "automatically" isn't the best word for describing this difference. But my answer contains also an explanation of that.